# Editing an APK file's resources from Android

Tags: android

I want to edit the resources of an APK file from WITHIN Android. I know how to do it with ApkTool in windows/linux, but I'm having problems doing it in an Android app itself.

In particular, I need to add a few files to the resouces, edit the AndroidManifest.xml and put the files back in the APK.
I know APKs are simply zip files, but the resources and manifest inside them are "compiled" in binary format so they cannot be edited directly, so I need some kind of library or tool for Android that can decompile the resources and then put them back in the APK.

I know this can be done, since apps like [APK Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor) do it (and without needing root!) but I can't find any documentation on how to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://github.com/xiaxiaocao/apk-parser) library for parsing an APK.

Comment: It can READ the resources, but what I need is the opposite, I need to repackage them in the APK.

Comment: You have to sign with the same key the application was signed. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630796/signing-apk-files-programmatically-in-java).

Comment: You're one step ahead. Before signing I have to put the files back in the APK. The problem is that the files (for example: the AndroidManifest.xml) are in an encoded format, you cannot put back in the plaintext files, they need to be converted to the AXML Binary format, something that is usually done by aapt (but I can't find an android port of aapt, if I did it would be easy)

Comment: Apktool is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool). Maybe you will find something in sources.

Comment: It's what I'm doing now, tho in the ApkTool FAQ it states that ApkTool doesn't work on Android itself, only on desktop OSes. The thing that annoys me is that I found an app that does it (linked in my question) so I KNOW it can be done... but can't find the proper tools.